# Java ArrayList not keeping elements

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist

I wrote a simple program where the user can make squares. I have a JOptionPane class that gives the user 3 options: 1. make a square, 2. show the made squares and 0. quit.
I want to store all the squares in an ArrayList so when the user chooses 2 it returns all the made squares, with a format() method.
So the JOptionPane class has a static arraylist, but it never keeps the stored squares.
This JOptionPane class is called by the main method class Launcher. But when I press 2 to show all the squares it returns nothing.
There is also a really simple class Position that sets a certian position with an x and y value.

Class square:

```
package domain;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Square {

    private Color color;
    private int size;
    private Position position;

    public Square(Color color, int size, Position position) {
        this.setColor(color);
        this.setSize(size);
        this.setPosition(position);
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
    public Position getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
    public void setPosition(Position position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String format() {
        return "Square with size " + this.getSize() + " on " +     this.getPosition().format(); 
    }

}
```

JOptionPane class:

```
package ui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import domain.Position;
import domain.Square;

public class JPaintMenu {

    public static ArrayList<Square> squares = new ArrayList<Square>();

    public int menu() {
        String choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("1. Create square\n2. Show squares\n\n0. Quit\nMake your choice:\n");
        return Integer.parseInt(choice);
    }

    public Square newSquare() {
        Color color = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Color of the square?", null);
        String sizeString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Size of the square?");
        int size = Integer.parseInt(sizeString);
        String xString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("X coordinate?");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(xString);
        String yString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Y coordinate?");
        int y = Integer.parseInt(yString);

        Position position = new Position(x, y);
        Square square = new Square(color, size, position);
        squares.add(square);
        return square;
    }

    public String format() {
        String result = "";
        for(Square square : squares) {
            result += square.format();
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

And the main method class Launcher:

```
package ui;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Launcher {

    public static JPaintMenu menu = new JPaintMenu();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = menu.menu();
        if(result == 1) {
            menu.newSquare();
        }
        if (result == 2) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, menu.format());
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: You're only performing one action each time you run the program. When the program exits, anything still just in memory is lost. You either need to store the results in a file (or something similar), or loop round giving the user the menu multiple times, until they quit...

Comment: You call the program multiple times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think either (1) you confuses *static* with *persistent*, or (2) your `main` method should be implemented in a loop.

With `static` one means you don't store the state of an object into another object, but shared over all objects of the same type. *Persistent* storage means you store the state of an object such that it is accessible the next time you call the program. In that case you need to *serialize* the data; and store it into a file (or webserver,...)

Another possibility is to make the program query the user multiple times; like:

```
int result = -1;
do {
    result = menu.menu();
    if(result == 1) {
        menu.newSquare();
    }
    if (result == 2) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, menu.format());
    }
} while(result == 1 || result == 2);
```